# What do angle brackets after a class name mean in a variable declaration?

Tags: delphi, syntax

I have been programming in Delphi for a while, but I never ran across a syntax that I found in a question here on SO. There was this syntax:

```
var Dic: TDictionary<Integer,string>;
```

I've never seen the `<type, type>`. What does it mean? When and where can it be used? I found nothing, since Google omits chars like '<', '>'.

Comment: Although Google omits most punctuation, searching for "Delphi TDictionary<Integer,string>" yields several results that give an idea of what's going on with that syntax. Mostly because TDictionary *always* includes angle brackets, so it doesn't matter whether they're part of the search.

Comment: This is the same basic syntax as Generics in C#, and looks very much the same as templated types in C++.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is the syntax used for generics. Generics allow you to define classes that are *parameterized* by type.

You can read all about it in the [Delphi documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Generics_Index). You may also find the [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_programming) page useful. It gives a broader overview of the concept of generic programming.

Comment: @martin Also, generics weren't introduced until Delphi 2009 (at least for native Delphi) so if you've spent most of your time in older versions of Delphi that would be why you've not encountered them.

Answer (score 6):

In many languages, it's usually a mapping, or template instantiation, Delphi calls these generics, and an example of declaring them can be seen [here](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Declaring_Generics):

```
type
  TPair<Tkey,TValue> = class   // TKey and TValue are type parameters
    FKey: TKey;
    FValue: TValue;
    function GetValue: TValue;
  end;

function TPair<TKey,TValue>.GetValue: TValue;
begin
  Result := FValue;
end;
```

What your particular example is defining is a dictionary that will map integers to strings.