# What is the purpose of the "<" and ">" in this statement

Tags: class, delphi

I came across this code and cannot understand what its purpose is:

```
  TDfmPropertyList = class(TobjectList<TDfmProperty>)
```

What is it telling me?

Comment: [This is well documented.](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Generics_Index)

Comment: @Andreas Rejbrand Yes, it's well documented, but without knowing that it's to do with generics, one wouldn't know what to look for in the documentation.

Comment: [Generics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_programming) now exist for 45+ years in many languages - if you have neither met this code nor this term your experience is questionable. Read about it and you should understand its advantages. The shortest summary is: avoiding very similar code just because the data type might differ. You could have searched for "[programming angular brackets](https://www.google.ca/search?q=programming+angular+brackets)". Linking [existing Q](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9801355/4299358).

Comment: @SetiNet: I'm sorry if I made you upset. But I didn't downvote your question, nor did I vote to close it. In fact, if you think about it, I essentially answered your Q but as a comment because of a true A, since this Q is just barely suitable for the Stack Overflow Q&A format.

Answer (score 5):

Delphi has two different `TObjectList` classes -

1. [`System.Contnrs.TObjectList`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Contnrs.TObjectList), which is a concrete class that holds a list of plain `TObject` pointers.
2. [`System.Generics.Collections.TObjectList<T>`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Alexandria/en/System.Generics.Collections.TObjectList), which is a [Generic](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Generics_Index) class that holds a list of whatever type the Generic parameter `T` specifies.

In this case, the `TDfmPropertyList` class is deriving from the *Generic* `TObjectList<T>` class which is holding elements of type `T=TDfmProperty`.